# self alias in closures

Tags: java, coding-style

I use closures in java code a lot and because of the requirement of the project to include 'this' alias to all instance fields and methods, I used to use 'self' alias to reference the outer scope instance variables in order to escape the ugliness of the code. f.ex.:

```
class SomeStrategyWithLongNameClass implements ... {

    private final SomeStrategyWithLongNameClass self = this;

    private SomeService someService;

    public Function<...> someMethod() {
         return new Function<>() {
             @Override 
             public Result apply(Argument x) {
                 ....
                 SomeVar var = self.someService.execute(...);
                 ....
                 return result;
             }
         }
    }
}
```

I know that it's also possible to reference with "`SomeStrategyWithLongNameClass.this`" to instance fields, but that, from my perspective, only pollutes the code, making it harder to read.

I've been suddenly told, w/o explanations, to stop using 'self' aliasing and to stick to 'Class.this' pattern.

could anyone tell is there a solid reason for this?

Comment: You should probably ask the people who told you to stop using it.

Comment: @Kayaman I tried, but couldn't get an answer :)

Comment: Yes. It is. That `self` highly kills the readability of code and I need to verify what is the type `self` each time I read your code. In case of `SomeStrategyWithLongNameClass.this`, that's self explanatory.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The fact that the project in question has the rule to use the `this` qualifier everywhere already tells a lot about the kind of culture and discipline it adopts. Clearly, conciseness is not the top priority, but obviousness and familiarity to Joe Developer is. Do not underestimate the value of these principles in a large enterprise project.

You have introduced a convention on your own which would now have to be followed by everyone to have a consistent codebase. A failure to implement it properly will lead to errors or bugs. The potential value of the idiom is outweighed by potential long-term damage.